# BeautifulSoup Returning "None" When Element Exists?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping in python, and it seems that some programs work and some don't randomly. I am trying to request a certain string of text from a page (located [here](https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/Captbugz) and in the html at:

```
<body class="fixed-left widescreen">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content-page">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 b-0 p-0">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="card-box m-b-10">
                                    <h4 class="m-t-0 header-title">Status</h4>
                                        <b>Offline</b>
```

), following [this](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) tutorial (not using the tutorial webpage for scraping), but when typing `print(results.prettify())`, it returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'`. So far, my complete code is

```
from requests import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/Captbugz'
page = get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='wrapper')
print(results.prettify())
```

Following the tutorial, the statement `print(results.prettify())` should've printed html code (and did while I was following the example), but returned `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'` instead. I have looked up the solution to this and I have found 1) Use Selenium and 2) The data isn't getting scraped in the first place. For 1), I don't believe the code I'm looking for would have any problems with Javascript (please correct me on this), and for 2), the `get(URL)` is actually returning something. I am fairly new to Stack Overflow, so please inform me if I am not following the rules for posting. Thanks!

Comment: The site is returning an "Access denied" error when you try to download it from Python.

Comment: @Barmar does this mean that there is no way to scrape from this site?

Comment: It depends on how it's determining that the request is coming from a script instead of a browser. You might be able to fix it by sending an appropriate User-Agent header.'

Comment: @Barmar sorry can you explain how to do that as i said i'm new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case (the URL you mentioned) there is no element with `id` equal to "wrapper". Thus, `soup.find(id='wrapper')` can not find anything and returns `None` as result, which of course has no method `prettify`. You should check, whether `results` is not equal to `None` (i.e. there is an element with the particular `id`) before calling `.prettify()`.

Since without proper browser headers you end up at Cloudflare, you should adapt your code to the following:

```py
from requests import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/Captbugz'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/108.0"}

page = get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='wrapper')
print(results)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the root problem of why the element can't be found. It's there if you access the page from a browser. And it's in the HTML source, not added dynamically by JS.

Comment: In fact, using the above URL brings you to Cloudflare instead of the real page, thus preventing you to access the desired page directly... Hence, no `wrapper` element... I changed my original answer accordingly to address for that

Comment: CloudFlare is simply the CDN the site uses to cache its pages. They're as "real" as anything coming from the actual site. Our site uses CF for all the static pages.

Comment: In this case, the site has restrictions on how it can be accessed, and uses CF to host the error page that they return when access is rejected.

Comment: That is true, however when requesting the original URL without browser headers, one receives the HTML code of the CDN, not the originally requested one. The redirect is done, when there is some sort of browser parsing going on (like Javascript execution), which is not the case for BeautifulSoup. Thus, we only parse the CDN site, that doesn't contain an element with `id === "wrapper"`

Comment: This edit of the answer worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, avoid using `from xxx import *`, as you can get issues with names, and it makes your code harder to read.

Your URL starts with `https`, and `request.get` will give you a 403 error:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/Captbugz'
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page)

--> <Response [403]>
```

HTTP 403 (Forbidden), is because you're trying to access a https website without a valid certificate:
[see : documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).

You can look at this questions on the 403 response:
[getting 403 error while using requests.get() python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092257/getting-403-error-while-using-requests-get-python)

edit:
In any case, this doesn't seem to be the cause of the error. The error seems to come from the wrapper part. If you omit it, the prettify() function seems to work, so the issue is finding the wrapper, as the page you get back (which is the error page due to the 403 error) doesn't have tags with `id='wrapper'`

```
from requests import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://plancke.io/hypixel/player/stats/Captbugz'
page = get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  #results = soup.find(id='wrapper')  remove this line
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Changing `https` to `http` still returns a 403 error.

Comment: I have used urlopen in the past, would that help here?

Comment: Ah. Good point. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @OnMyTerms Look at the linked question for suggestions.

Comment: I don't think that's something you normally need to deal with yourself, it should be handled automatically by the `requests` module.

Comment: when I run your code using the `https` address, I get your 'None' error, however, if I type `print(soup)` I get the source of the page, so it seems the error is in the last two lines of your code

Comment: See @Lecraminos's answer. Just adding the User-Agent header fixes it.

Comment: @XaC Without the User-Agent header, the response contains an error page, not the real page.

Comment: it seems the issues is the `wrapper` part, that is not found, as the error page doesn't have it, so there is nothing to find, hence the `None`